# Group counts in new column

Tags: pandas, group-by

I want a new column "group_count". This shows me in **how many groups in total the attribute occurs.**

```
       Group  Attribute  group_count
    0      1         10              4
    1      1         10              4
    2      1         10              4
    3      2         10              4
    4      2         20              1
    5      3         30              1
    6      3         10              4
    7      4         10              4
```

I tried to groupby Group and attributes and then transform by using count

```
df["group_count"] = df.groupby(["Group", "Attributes"])["Attributes"].transform("count")

       Group  Attribute  group_count
0      1         10            3
1      1         10            3
2      1         10            3
3      2         10            1
4      2         20            1
5      3         30            1
6      3         10            1
7      4         10            1
```

But it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) with `transform`:

```
df['group_count1'] = df.groupby('Attribute')['Group'].transform('nunique')
print (df)
   Group  Attribute  group_count  group_count1
0      1         10            4             4
1      1         10            4             4
2      1         10            4             4
3      2         10            4             4
4      2         20            1             1
5      3         30            1             1
6      3         10            4             4
7      4         10            4             4
```

Comment: there is a small typo: it's value_counts()

Comment: @jezrael Thank you for your response. I updated my question. I want to know in how many groups the attribute occurs. Therefore in a row which has Attribute 10, it occurs in 4 groups in total.

Answer (score 2):

Use `df.drop_duplicates(['Group','Attribute'])` to get unique `Attribute` per `group` , then groupby on `Atttribute` to get count of `Group`, finally `map` with original `Attribute` column.

```
m=df.drop_duplicates(['Group','Attribute'])
df['group_count']=df['Attribute'].map(m.groupby('Attribute')['Group'].count())
print(df)
```

---

```
   Group  Attribute  group_count
0      1         10            4
1      1         10            4
2      1         10            4
3      2         10            4
4      2         20            1
5      3         30            1
6      3         10            4
7      4         10            4
```